# equivalent char* in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a dll that is written in c++. And I am p/invoking to call the functions.

I have this c++ declaration.

```
int dll_registerAccount(char* username, char* password);
```

I have done this dllimport declaration:

```
[DllImport("pjsipDlld")]
static extern int dll_registerAccount(IntPtr username, IntPtr password);
```

Would my DllImport be the equivalent to the c++ using IntPtr?

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: Since you're using the Sipek SDK from http://sites.google.com/site/sipekvoip/sipeksdk, may I ask why you're doing your own `DllImport` when the SDK already provides wrappers for you?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The C# way of doing this is by letting the marshaler handle the `char*` stuff while you work with a string:

```
[DllImport("pjsipDlld")]
static extern int dll_registerAccount(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string username,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string password);
```

Replace `LPStr` with `LPWStr` if you're working with wide chars.

Comment: What if the C declaration is : 
__declspec(dllexport) MyErrCode GetTrustTypes(const char* bundleName, char ***trustTypes);

What should be the corresponding declaration in C# ?

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of calling conventions, this tripped me up. In my case I need to call a C++ DLL but with C-style exports, which uses the `cdecl` calling convention. If you have the luxury of having the source Visual Studio Solution, go to Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced and find it under "Calling Convention". This fix it for me:

```
[DllImport(DllName, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
// bool MyFunction(char* fileName) <-- From the DLL
static extern bool MyFunction(string fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[DllImport("DLL loction"), EntryPoint = "dll_registerAccount",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
static extern int dll_registerAccount(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string username,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string password);
```

- `cdecl` is the default calling convention for C and C++ programs,
- refer these [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
    [DllImport("pjsipDlld", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern int dll_registerAccount(string username, string password);
```

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder for char*, since the length is unknown?

```
[DllImport("pjsipDlld")]
static extern int dll_registerAccount(StringBuilder username, StringBuilder password);
```

Comment: The length might be unknown, but what comes in and what gets out are constant strings (taken separatly of course, they dont have to be the same thing), so they map perfectly to a `string` object.

Comment: Yes, I readup on those attributes (LPStr & LPWStr) after seeing your answer. Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: This ended up working perfectly for me when calling Fortran subroutine from C#, while the accepted answer did not.  I had a known length too and this is the version that worked. YMMV.