# C# dll call not passing char* to C++ MFC regular dll

Tags: c#, pointers, dll, dllimport

I have a C++ MFC regular DLL I am calling with the following:

```
public static class Access3rdPartyDLL
{
  public static string FilePath;
  [DllImport("3rdparty.dll")]  
  // I have also tried LPWStr
  public static extern long Download([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string sDownloadFile,
                                   int iDeviceNum
                                   ...);

  public static long DownloadToDevice()
  {
    long result;
    string FilePath = "C:\\myfile.txt"
    result = Download(FilePath, 1, ...);
    // check if success or error
    if(result > 0)
    ...
  }
}
```

I get an error back from the DLL saying "File: 'C:\myfile.txt' not found. But its there...
I have also tried using `StringBuilder` but this also fails.

Could this be a problem with the DLL or am I doing something wrong?
I found this current code here:  [SO: equivalent char* in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450731/equivalent-char-in-c)

EDIT: I have done this in C++ before and this code works:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) HRESULT __stdcall Download(char* sDownloadFile, int ...
```

which I call with:

```
HRESULT result = Download(file_for_download, 1, .. // where file_for_download is a char*
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the C++ method signature ?

Comment: Show us the C++ function definition and implementation.

Comment: I do not have the dll code but I do have this working in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing wrong with the P/invoke is that you are using C# `long` which is 64 bits, but an `HRESULT` is only 32 bits.

You have matching calling conventions, default marshalling for managed `string` is `char*` on the unmanaged side.

Mismatching return value size would not explain why your C# code receives a string message `File: 'C:\myfile.txt' not found` so your main problem most likely lies in the code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Wouldn't the extra bits just be ignored (curious not nit-picking)?

Comment: @Brandon Yes I expect so. I certainly can't see this mismatch producing different behaviour in the DLL.

Comment: @Nick Well, now that you have corrected those parts of the P/invoke that you have shown here, you can start looking elsewhere for the problem. The problem could be in the P/invoke bits that you didn't show us, or in how you are calling the DLL.

Comment: As an aside, the DLL declaration should really be `const char*` since presumably it isn't writing to the file name.

Comment: There really isnt any other code to show. 
`const char*` for the c++ code?

Comment: @Nick Well, I don't know where the problem is, but it isn't in any of the code you've shown here. And yes, `const char*` for the C++ code but that won't be your problem, that's just good practice.

Comment: Aaaand you were right. Found some code elsewhere that created a Stream to that same file and didnt close it. So it all works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why the following wouldn't work in this simple scenario:

```
[DllImport( "3rdparty.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi )]
static extern long Download(string sDownloadFile, int iDeviceNum, ...)

long result = Download("C:\\myfile.txt", 1, ...);
```

Comment: That's identical to the code in the question. So you will get the same error.

Comment: @David Yeah, I mean... Basically, I'm agreeing with you that it's not an "interop" problem, as it's most likely an error in the native code implementation.