# Passing stringbuilder or byte[] from C# to unmanaged API cashes with exception Access Violation

Tags: c#

I have an unmanaged API whose signature is:

```
int ImportFile( char *sFileName )
```

where Filename is Name of the file to import,full path and file name.

So I am using this API inside my C# code as:

```
string StepFilePath = @"C:\Users\pandey\AppData\Local\Temp\W-00004_CAD.stp";

StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder(256);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(StepFilePath))
{
    Sb.Append(StepFilePath);
}

int a = API.ImportFile(Sb);
```

At this point it crashes giving error Access Violation reading location error. I even tried to use byte[] in place of stringbuilder but it didnt work.

I have declared this API in a separate API.cs file like this :

```
[DllImport("exe name", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
unsafe extern static public int ImportFile(StringBuilder aStringBuilder);
```

Any ideas what could be the issue? Should I use something else in place of StringBuilder or byte[].

Comment: A `StringBuilder` isn't going to be compatible with `char*`, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450731/equivalent-char-in-c-sharp

Comment: You use `StringBuilder` when the method modifies the `string`... Here `ImportFile` doesn't need to modify anything. Use `ImportFile(string str)`

Comment: StringBuilder is okay, even if it is not necessary.   Send a copy of your test program to the programmer that wrote this DLL so he can debug his code.

Comment: Yes actually I tried with normal string and as well as using MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] attribute but nothing worked. I will send the program to the programmer.