# How to declare a pointer to a character array in C# (importing C library function)?

Tags: c#, c, arrays, pointers

I have a library written in C, and I'm supposed to use this library in C#. I don't have access to the source code.

The original function is defined as

```
typedef char TYPE[32];
int function(TYPE* text);
```

Now, if my C knowledge is okay, that would be the equivalent of `char (*text)[32]`. How do I port this to C#?

EDIT: I have a DLL and a header file. The typedef and the function are declared in the header file. I'm supposed to DllImport this function to my C# code. How do I do that?

Comment: you need to read up on P/Invoke. That is the droid you are using for old Unamanged code you are calling.

Comment: Your google-fu is weak :) See [Mattias Sjögren's answer](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/277801-how-define-pointer-array#post1110684) (Nov 17 '05) on bytes.com.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your answers, but I may not be able to express myself correcty. Please see my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [equivalent char\* in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450731/equivalent-char-in-c-sharp)