# C/C++ DLL failing after .NET framework upgrade from 3.5 to 4.6

Tags: c#, c++, windows-10-desktop

I have application called as Agent which have 2 projects :

1. C# project
2. C/C++ DLL

Whole application was running fine with .NET 3.5 which we use to build with vs2008.
Due to some requirement we upgraded the .Net Framework to 4.6 and vs 2019 to build this up.
Now my application service runs but looks like C/C++ dll exports are failing somewhere.
What I have tried:
C# side

```
TAgtLib.TAStartAgent(mServerPort, mName, mBinDir, mPath, mDebug,
                    mStdout, mDefaultLogDays, mEncryptOnly);
```

where TAgtLib is wrapper class which declares these C/C++ function like this

```
[DllImport("ccplusplus.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int TAStartAgent(int port, string name, string bindir, string rundir, string debugOption, string stdoutOption, int mDefaultLogDays, int encryptonly);
```

C++ definition :

```
extern "C" int _stdcall TAStartAgent(int PortNum, char *Name, char *binDir, char *runDir, char *debugOption, char *stdoutOption, int mDefaultLogDays, int encryptonly);
```

Whenever debugging is hitting on this function from c# it goes into memory violation.

When we changed to binDir.ToArray() and changed the dllexport declaration as char[] binDir ,simmilary for runDir,it didnt gave access violation but it went inside the dll.

Though C dll still giving issues.

Can someone please guide me off what is that must be effecting the c/c++ dll after this migration from 3.5 to 4.6?

I am novice wrt C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely happening because .Net 4 changed the way that it corrects incorrect P/Invoke calling conventions.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ee941656(v=vs.100):

> To improve performance in interoperability with unmanaged code,
>   incorrect calling conventions in a platform invoke now cause the
>   application to fail. In previous versions, the marshaling layer
>   resolved these errors up the stack.

To solve this, you must specify the correct calling convention in the P/Invoke declaration, e.g.

```
DllImport("ccplusplus.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int TAStartAgent(int port, string name, string bindir, string rundir, string debugOption, string stdoutOption, int mDefaultLogDays, int encryptonly);
```

Although you will of course need to specify the correct calling convention for your DLL.

Comment: Thanks. I updated but still its having memory corruption error.

Comment: @user8750269 But did you try all the different calling conventions? You probably just haven't chosen the correct one. Also, if you run it under the debugger it should tell you which one to use.

Comment: Yes tried. My debugger is not jumping into C dll from C#. Till c# it fine but its not jumping.I created a test c# project and dll for that debugger is working. Tried same setting on my project as well, its not!!!

Comment: Still i feel its problem with the strings which are being passed from C# to C++. looks like default marshaling works for all parameters except these two parms.

Comment: I haven't received the same error, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us?

Comment: Its happening with my existing project and not with new ones

Comment: I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450731/equivalent-char-in-c-sharp) mentioned how to pass the equivalent char* type in C#, you can check it.